# Why is this always returning empty folder found when there's not empty folder?

Tags: shell, sh

I have this script and it's always returning echo "Empty folder found."

If I run the command  `find $RootFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty | wc -l | xargs`, it returns 0, because there's no empty folder there.

However, the function always return as if there's empty folder, returning echo "Empty folder found."

Any idea?

Thanks

```
RootFolder="/data/output/folder" #Must change to your default output folder. Originally, it's "/data/outpu$
FindEmptyFolders=$(find $RootFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty | wc -l | xargs)

  if [ "$FindEmptyFolders" > 0 ];
  then
    echo "Empty folder found."
  else
    echo "No empty folders found."
  fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` is not valid `[` test argument. You need to use `-gt` (from Greather Than). From [man test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2
>   INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2

I don't know what `| xargs` on the end is supposed to do. Also quote your variables.

```
RootFolder="/data/output/folder" 
FindEmptyFolders=$(find "$RootFolder" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty | wc -l)

  if [ "$FindEmptyFolders" -gt 0 ];
  then
    echo "Empty folder found."
  else
    echo "No empty folders found."
  fi
```

Or you can use `>` as in C language by using `((` compound command with shell arithmetic, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

```
if (( FindEmptyFolders > 0 )); then
    echo "Empty folder found."
  else
    echo "No empty folders found."
  fi
```

Comment: Although `-gt` would be the desired operator here, many implementations (though not required by POSIX) appear to use `>` for lexicographic comparison. It does need to be escaped to prevent the shell from treating it as a redirection operator, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the shell `> 0` means "create a file called `0` (or clobber it if it already exists), then redirect standard output to that file".

For example,

```
echo hello > 0
```

writes `hello` to a file called `0`.

Output redirections like this can appear anywhere on the command line:

```
echo > 0 hello
> 0 echo hello
```

all do the same thing.

Similarly,

```
[ "$FindEmptyFolders" > 0 ]
```

is equivalent to

```
[ "$FindEmptyFolders" ] > 0
```

and means "test whether `$FindEmptyFolders` is a non-empty string and write the output to a file called `0`".

The `[` command produces no output, so this effectively always produces an empty file called `0`. The condition is always true because any number (even `0`) is a non-empty string.

---

To perform a numeric "greater than" test, you need to write

```
[ "$FindEmptyFolders" -gt 0 ]
```